# Incompatible ranks in assignment of a function result in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I want to make a function that returns a max absolute value in matrix, but the compiler returns this error

```
 mv = maxVal(a, n)
 1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)
```

This is my Fortran code

```
    real*8, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: a
    integer :: n
    real*8 :: mv

    read*, n
    allocate(a(n, n))
    read*, a

    mv = maxVal(a, n)
end

real*8 function maxVal(a, n)
       integer :: n
       integer :: i, j, max
       integer, dimension(2) :: index
       real*8, dimension(n, n) :: a
       max = abs(a(1, 1))
       index = (/1, 1/)
       do i = 1, size(a)
          do j = 1, size(a, 1)
             if (abs(a(i, j)) .gt. max) then
                max = abs(a(i, j))
                index = (/i, j/)
             endif
          end do
       end do
       maxVal = a(index(1), index(2))
       return
end
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the error message. Please use the [edit] function next time to avoid having a closed down-voted question. If you have more of them it can lead to a ban. See how I edited this question to make it easier to read and more straightforward. You don't really have to use the `<br>` at StackOverflow.

Comment: I suggest you to learn about modules and internal functions. They are very important to Fortran 90 and later versions and will help you to diagnose some of these errors.

Answer (score 3):

MAXVAL is a Fortran intrinsic function. Since your main program does not declare your MaxVal to be EXTERNAL, nor is there an explicit interface for it, the compiler assumes you are using the intrinsic. (If you declare it EXTERNAL you also need to declare it REAL*8. And I'll be pedantic and suggest that you should not be using extensions such as REAL*8 when the language has standard methods for doing such things.)

MAXVAL, when the DIM argument (second argument) is supplied always returns an array if the first argument has rank greater than 1 - this is why the compiler complains because an array cannot be assigned to a scalar.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876853/what-are-problems-in-my-code

Comment: it seems like the compiler could provide a more informative error  message in this situation. "Warning user defined symbol name conflicts with intrinsic"

Comment: Most Fortran compilers don't issue such warnings as doing that is bog-standard Fortran and it would trigger unwanted warnings in many applications. In many cases the compiler will complain if the arguments don't match what the intrinsic expects, but here they do. The real answer is to use modules or internal procedures so that explicit interfaces are available, and not rely on implicit interfaces.